# I can see Age in a Contact Summary. How can I add Age to a Profile?

Tags: contacts, custom-fields, profile, drupal-views

I can see Age for a contact in the Contact Summary screen, which is not a built-in field, but is apparently calculated from the Birth Date field. I can add the Birth Date field to a Profile. How can I also/instead display the calculated Age as a Profile field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good questions. As you say, age is a calculated field and afaik won't be available.

Either you need to adjust how the DoB field is displayed which may be via js.

Only other option, for display purposes, would be to build (you guessed it) a  Drupal view block and show that instead.